# Android ADB Wireless Scan

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to do a wifi scan with android adb/shell?

I have a Nexus 7 unlocked and rooted with Super User and busy box installed.

I can turn the wifi on or off, check the state, and get the current connected network, but cannot seem to find something that will scan for wifi connections.

I don't have wpa_cli available, but if its a must have for this functionality, is there a go-to article on installing/compiling it for my device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `WifiManager.startScan()` do `adb shell su 0 service call wifi 11`

Comment: Fantastic thanks very much! For me it was slightly different, instead of 11 I have to call 13, apparently its different for different devices.

Comment: `13` is `WifiManager.getScanResults()`. you did not ask about "getting results" just about "doing the scan". To get results you need to `service call wifi 11` then wait for a 2-3 seconds then `service call wifi 13`

Comment: also this post explains how to find transaction codes for your specific android version http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/calling-android-services-from-adb-shell.html